# How to add a .hover effect to a div?

Tags: jquery, css, hover

I am pretty new to programming but I cant seem to add an `.hover` effect using **jquery**.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.mainr').hover(
    function() {
      $(this).addClass('.mainh')
    },
    function() {
      $(this).removeClass('mainh')
    });
});
```

```css
.main {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  width: 60%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #D8D8D8;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.mainr {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 50%;
  width: 23%;
  height: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #0B0B3B;
  float: left;
  color: #D8D8D8;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: 50%;
  font: 20px"Interstate", "Lucida Grande", Arial;
}
.mainh {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 23%;
  height: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #D8D8D8;
  float: left;
  color: #0B0B3B;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: 50%;
  font: 20px"Interstate", "Lucida Grande", Arial;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="mainr">Register</div>
</div>
```

and could you also tell mehow to center the text inside the div (setting the height)

Thanks,

Comment: What's wrong with using CSS `:hover`?

Comment: You should not add the dot in your `addClass` call. Please replace `$(this).addClass('.mainh')` with `$(this).addClass('mainh')` And add jQuery library

Comment: Maybe you can use toggleClass('mainh') instead of using both addClass and removeClass

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by CSS too. No need of JS:

Try this:

```
.mainr:hover {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 23%;
    height: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #D8D8D8;
    float:left;
    color: #0B0B3B;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:50%;
    font: 20px "Interstate","Lucida Grande",Arial;
}
```

Replace **`.mainh`** with **`.mainr:hover`** and this will work for you without any JS. cheers!!!

**EDITED:**

In your JS code there is minor mistake:

```
$('.mainr').hover(
function() {
  $(this).addClass('mainh');
},
function() {
  $(this).removeClass('mainh');
}
);
```

Try the above this will work.

Problem was       `$(this).addClass('.mainh');` in this line you have write `.mainh` which should be `mainh`. In JS there is no need to give `.` to class if you are class name, means you are using it in function. `.` is used the selectors only.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stay in jQuery you have to correct your mistake and remove the `.` on your `addClass` call :

```
$('.mainr').hover( 
   function(){ $(this).addClass('mainh') },
   function(){ $(this).removeClass('mainh') }
);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ho535xn0/2/)

But the easiest solution is to use CSS like in [@CodeLღver answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29793678/how-to-add-a-hover-effect-to-a-div/29793950#29793825)

Answer (score 1):

You Forgot to add the Jquery library and there is one mistake in code .When you addClass you need not to put the .(dot) for that.Actual code will be like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.mainr').hover(
    function() {$(this).addClass('mainh')},
    function() {$(this).removeClass('mainh')}
  );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure you have include the jquery library.

And you may try to use toggleClass instead of addClass and removeClass

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.mainr').hover( 
       function(){ 
          $(this).toggleClass('mainh'); 
       }
    );
});
```

And to vertical center the word inside the div, just add the following three line in the div css

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/d5t2fLLh/1/

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ho535xn0/3/)

In order to add CSS hover effect using jQuery you can do `$(this).css('PROPERTY','VALUE') }`

Answer (score 0):

Adding a hover state to an element is durn easy. Let's use an opacity change as an example:

```
div
{
opacity:1.0;
}
div{
opacity:0.5
}
```

But what if we want to have that hover state apply to everything but the element actually being hovered over? (e.g. other adjacent sibling divs)

Let's assume this basic HTML:

```
<section class=parent>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div> 
</section>
```

We'll apply the current CSS properties to all the children of the parent when the parent is in the hover state.

```
.parent:hover > div {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Then when the parent is hovered and the individual div is hovered, we bump the opacity back up, giving the final effect we are looking for.

```
.parent:hover > div {
  opacity: 1.0;
}
```